# WSO2 developer studio creating a web application

Tags: eclipse, wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I am following developer studio tutorial to create my first web application 
but it is not working as described. I am using eclipse-jee-juno. On creating web application, there will be another input form to enter other informations, but in the tutorial 'choosing target runtime', 'dynamic web module version', 'configuration' or other things are not explained.

When I finish. I didnt get JSP file. but as per tutorial, it will be created and opened. Do guide me regarding this.

I was confusing to follow the same procedure of "Creating web application" by developer studio version 3.1.0 and other latest version e.g. 3.2.0.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS310/Creating+a+Web+Application

[2] http://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS320/Creating+a+Web+Application

in the first one, JSP file is automatically created. After finish, "you will see a Web Application being created in the workspace and index.jsp file being opened for you."

But, in the [2], none of the JSP file is created. Why??

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Steps 4,5 and 6 in the article you've linked explain 'choosing target runtime', 'dynamic web module version'and other configuration details. You only need to specify correct runtime of Carbon server. For others default values are ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create a JSP file you can do it manually after creating the web app.

From eclipse help,

> In the Project Explorer, expand your project and right click on your
>   WebContent folder or on a subfolder under WebContent. Note that if you
>   choose any other folder in which to create the JSP, then it will not
>   be included in the WAR file that is deployed to the server. In
>   addition, link validation will not encompass files that are not under
>   the WebContent folder.
>
> From the context menu, select New > JSP. The
>   New Java Server Page window appears with your folder selected
>
> Type a
>   file name into the File name field, making sure you include the jsp
>   extension (jsp, jsv, jtpl, or jspx) in the file name.
>
> You have several
>   options for proceeding:
>
> - To accept the defaults associated with a new JSP file, select Finish.
> - To link to a file in the file system and specify path variables,
>     select Advanced and then make your selections using the Browse and
>     Variables buttons.
> - To use a template file for the initial content of
>     your JSP page, select Next. The 
>     Select JSP Template window appears. Select the Use JSP Template check
>     box, and then select one of the sample templates. You can also select
>     the JSP Templates link to add or remove JSP templates to your list of
>     templates.

You can use one of the templates to quickly create a JSP file.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Oracle JDK 1.7 with Developer Studio 3.2.0.

http://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS320/Installation